# CSS: css transition between slides similar to example

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple code which is changing slides on click on arrows or dots.

There is no transition between changing the content of slides.

Is there any option on how to add a transition between slides like is in a link?

[LINK](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/21814379434665818/sent/?invite_code=bb14cbcc549045338d647b570d3e070f&sender=737323907652047207&sfo=1)

I already tried animation with fade in and fade out but that is not what I want. I want to make an animation similar to an example in the link. It may a little bit slide and that decreases opacity and reverse.

Is there any option how to I can get I like this?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
    <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
    <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
    <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using `display` which does not accept a number, so it can't be animated by CSS. You'll need to use something like `opacity` or `transform: translate()`

Here is an example using opacity

Also consider using `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()`. They are much easier.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  width: 100%;

  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.mySlides.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.dot.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
    <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
    <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
    <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```